# My legend button is not working while click on them

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[image]    let data = ['container','container2','container3']

```
data.forEach(e[![enter image description here][2]][2]lement => {                
Highcharts.chart(element, {
    colors: ['#FF1D25', '#7AC943', '#792CDB', '#FCEE21'],
    chart: {
        type: 'pie',
        events:{
            render : function(){
            var series = this.series[0]
            seriesCenter = series.center,
            x = seriesCenter[0] + this.plotLeft,
            y = seriesCenter[1] + this.plotTop,
            text = 'Total: ' + series.total,
            fontMetrics = this.renderer.fontMetrics(16);
            if (!this.customTitle) {
                this.customTitle = this.renderer.text(
                    text,
                    null,
                    null,
                    true
                  )
                .css({
            transform: 'translate(-50%)',
            fontSize: '32px',
            color: 'black'
        })
        .add();
    }
    this.customTitle.attr({
        x,
        y: y + fontMetrics.f / 2
      });
    }
  }
},

    accessibility: {
        point: {
            valueSuffix: '%'
        }
    },
    
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
              },
            showInLegend: true
        }
    },


    series: [{
        name: 'Registrations',
        colorByPoint: true,
        innerSize: '75%',
        text: "Test",
        data: [{
            name: 'Total Servey',
            y: 68.1,
            
        }, {
            name: 'Approved',
            y: 11.0
        }, {
            name: 'Review pending',
            y: 11.2
        }, {
            name: 'Rejected',
            y: 9.7,
        }
    ]
}]
});
});
```

*Inside the image few legend button is not working. once when I remove the css which is applying over the pie chart, it's starting work while click on legend button,
As there are three pie chart in a row and the legend button of 1st pie chart is not working, on another hand in the second pie chart only 1st and 2nd button is working and similarly in the 3rd one all legends are working

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=highcharts+text+inside+chart+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Hi @SUDHANSHU SHEKHAR SRIVASTAVA, I've used your code to create this live example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hfoj7qw4/ but everything seems to work as expected. Could you add more details about the problem?

Comment: please check on link https://jsfiddle.net/Sudhanshu7458/mavrqs94/3/ As i have added HTML CSS JS but it is not look like responsive. please ignore the responsivness. and look into legend button which is related to the each pie

Comment: and when  you remove css, it will work fine

Comment: That's because the charts overlap. Are you sure that's the correct behavior?